# Keycloak Custom User Storage Provider (assigned roles set / effective roles empty)

Tags: keycloak

I am writing a custom UserStorageProvider for Keycloak against a HTTP-Service which contains only user information but no role information.

I want to accomplish that all users from this service are assigned to a composite role which is already existent in keycloak. As you can see I am resolving the the aggregated roles for composite role manually which is not really keen.

**Main problem is, that the roles I assign here in the following AbstractUserAdapter** are **visible** in the admin console in Keycloak **under "assigned roles" but not in the "effective roles"**. Consequently they are not mapped into my bearer token.

```
@Override
public Set<RoleModel> getClientRoleMappings(ClientModel app) {
    Set<RoleModel> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (RoleModel role : app.getRoles()) {
        if("my_keycloak_comp_role".equals(role.getName())) {
            result.add(role);
            if (role.isComposite()) {
                result.addAll(role.getComposites());
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning them to the users?

Comment: As seen in the above code in an implementation of an  AbstractUserAdapter

Comment: Okey, I get, but the roles that you want to add to users are client roles or realm roles?, meaning why have you chosen getClientRoleMappings and not getRealmRoleMappings?

Comment: I am only considering client roles in my project. The default realm roles are assigned correctly but I am not doing it in my code

Comment: Did you try to add log inside the method getClientRoleMappings to see if it is actually be called? btw I am sure about "result.addAll(role.getComposites());" how does it work for composite of composite

Comment: yeah  it works, if I search for a user in the keycloak admin console I ll see the mapped roles but only in the section "assigned roles" not in the section "effective roles"

Comment: That is pretty weird, because effective roles are just Assigned Roles + the composite roles

Comment: I got a lead. If you look at https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/ClientRoleMappingsResource.java (getCompositeClientRoleMappings) which is responsible for the  effective roles you can see that the User:hasRole method is involved and that's my error. I need an implementation of hasRole or better I am overriding the getRoleMappingsInternal method

Comment: Yep, you are right that makes sense, otherwise it assumes that the user does not have the role, but this approach starts to look a bit fragile. btw if you want to shared a particular line of code in git, you just need to click on that line https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/ClientRoleMappingsResource.java#L114